# What does bindMemory(to:capacity:) actually do?

Tags: swift, allocation, memory-layout

Apples documentation of the method `bindMemory(to:capacity:)` on `UnsafeRawPointer` states:

> Use the bindMemory(to:capacity:) method to bind the memory referenced
>   by this pointer to the type T.

What does binding the memory to a type mean?. Is it moving the bytes to a location in memory, so that `alignment` for the type is satisfied? Is it a costly operation?

I have to use it frequently in my codebase and need to know the costs involved.

**PS: I know it's usage to make sense out of the bytes. What I want to know is what does it do as a part of the binding process.**

Comment: There is some good information in https://forums.swift.org/t/what-is-binding-memory/4418, such as *“Binding memory communicates to the compiler that the memory locations are safe for typed access. Nothing happens at runtime--until someone writes a type safety sanitizer. ...”* and *“... a call to bindMemory(to:capacity:) has no observable runtime side effects at the point of the call”*

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47940167/2976878