# How to convert Data to UnsafePointer<UInt8>?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

In Swift I want to pass a data buffer (named `data`) of type `Data` to a C function (named `do_something`) that takes a pointer of type `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`.

Is the code example below correct? And if so, in this case is it OK to use `assumingMemoryBound(to:)` instead of `bindMemory(to:capacity:)`?

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { (unsafeBytes) in
  let bytes = unsafeBytes.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
  do_something(bytes, unsafeBytes.count)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is to use `bindMemory()`:

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { (unsafeBytes) in
    let bytes = unsafeBytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!
    do_something(bytes, unsafeBytes.count)
}
```

`assumingMemoryBound()` must only be used if the memory is already bound to the specified type.

Some resources about this topic:

- [UnsafeRawPointer Migration Guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html)
- [UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md#memory-model-explanation)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken isn't it easier to convert `Data` to `[UInt8]` and pass this as a pointer?

Comment: @vadian: Easier to code but less efficient at runtime. It would create an additional (temporary) array.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you know the memory hasn't already been bound to the `UInt8` type?

Comment: @ma11hew28: bindMemory binds or rebinds the memory location, so it does not matter if it is already bound to UInt8. There is also good information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942269/1187415. Note also that *“Binding memory communicates to the compiler that the memory locations are safe for typed access. Nothing happens at runtime--until someone writes a type safety sanitizer.”*

Comment: OK. But I want my app to run fast. Are you saying that even if I (unnecessarily) rebind memory to a type that it's already bound to, then my app will run just as fast (as if I hadn't)?

Comment: I also want my code to be coherent. [UnsafeRawBufferPointer | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawbufferpointer) says: "Each byte in memory is viewed as a `UInt8` value independent of the type of values held in that memory." So I don't understand why I can't assume it's already been bound to the `UInt8` type. I know it goes on to say: "To access the underlying memory through typed operations, the memory must be bound to a trivial type." But that seems like it'd only be necessary if you want to bind the memory to a type other than `UInt8`.

Comment: @ma11hew28: Speed is not affected. As mentioned in the Q&A that I referenced above, nothing happens at runtime (there is also a link to a posting from Apple Developer Andrew Trick in the Swift forum  confirming that).

Comment: @ma11hew28: A `Data` object holds the bytes in some (opaque) memory location. One can not know if or what that memory is bound to.

Comment: OK. Thank you, @MartinR.